# Scrapy item pipelines parallel or sequential execution of process_item

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm developing a scrapy spider, which is successfully yielding some items. Those items should be inserted into a database using pymysql. Because the data is relational, for every item I have to execute a few insertion statements. 
I'd like to call `connection.commit()` after every entire insertion to make sure that occuring errors do not cause inconsistent entries in my database.

I'm currently wondering whether scrapy will call `process_item` parallel for more than one item or sequentially for one item after another. If the latter is the case, I could simply use the following approach:

```
def process_item(self, item, spider):
    # execute insert statements
    connection.commit()
```

If more than one call to `process_item` is executed at the same time by scrapy, the call to `commit()` at the end could be called while another item is not fully inserted.

The [documentation for item pipelines](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html) states:

> After an item has been scraped by a spider, it is sent to the Item Pipeline which processes it through several components that are executed sequentially.

But I'm not quite sure whether that means that `process_item` will never be executed in parallel, or just that different Pipelines would always be executed one after another (for example Dropping Duplicates -> Changing something -> DB Insertion).

---

I think that `process_item` will be executed sequentially, as the documentation shows the following example:

```
class DuplicatesPipeline(object):

def __init__(self):
    self.ids_seen = set()

def process_item(self, item, spider):
    if item['id'] in self.ids_seen:
        raise DropItem("Duplicate item found: %s" % item)
    else:
        self.ids_seen.add(item['id'])
        return item
```

In this code, there is no synchronization for adding the id to `ids_seen` involved, nevertheless I don't know if the example is simplified because it only demonstrates how to use pipelines.

Comment: just curious but u figure out the answer?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Documentation for the [CONCURRENT_ITEMS](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#concurrent-items) setting specifies that items are processed in paralell (at least within a single response). I think setting it to `1` might help in your case.

I'm no expert on this part of Scrapy, but I believe [this is where it happens](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/1.4/scrapy/core/scraper.py#L170-L196).

Comment: Thanks, somehow I haven't seen this option!